# dotnet test not creating test results folder

Tags: asp.net-core, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, dotnet-test

As part of our **ASP.NET Core 2.0** build process I have added a *dotnet test* command which I have added as a Windows batch file.

Here is my command.

```
dotnet test "MyProject.csproj" --no-restore --results-directory "MyProject\TestResults" --verbosity minimal
```

And here is the output when run from the command line.

[image]

So it all appears to work correctly, yet no test results / test output is created.

Comment: Can you create the test results folder when you run the dotnet test on the agent machine directly? I mean run in command line locally.

Comment: The above screenshot was taken from the build server. Do you mean try this on my local dev machine?

Comment: Yes, you can have a try on you local dev machine to check if the test results folder can be created. Also, you can try specify a logger for test results (`-l|--logger <LoggerUri/FriendlyName>`) to check if that works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To output the test results from dotnet test, you can try pass `-xml /some/path/out.xml` or use the `work` parameter, like this: `dotnet test --work:"mypath/myresult.xml"`. See below threads for details:

- [dotnet test - Output test results](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3114)
- [Is there a way to specify TestResult.xml location?](https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit/issues/100)

---

Besides, generally you need to specify the argument `-l|--logger <LoggerUri/FriendlyName>` which specifies a logger for test results.

e.g.:

`dotnet test "myproject.csproj" --logger "trx;LogFileName=path\to\tests\folder\results.trx"` or 
`dotnet test "myproject.csproj" -l:"trx;LogFileName=path\to\tests\folder\results.trx"`

To make the generated `trx` files available as test results in VSTS/TFS, you can use the "Publish Test Results" task:

[image]

Comment: dotnet test doesn't recognse either the --xml or --work parameters. Presumably to publish my test results I need to execute the unit tests first which is why I am trying to get dotnet test to work.

Comment: Following the first link I came across the following syntax which works.

dotnet test "myproject.csproj" --logger "trx;LogFileName=path\to\tests\folder\results.trx"

Comment: `--logger` parameter shall be included in quotes.

Answer (score 35):

To output the test results using the `dotnet test` option `--results-directory` you have to also set `--logger`.

The `-xml` and `--work` options no longer work as they are not part of the options provided by the test CLI. I remember have used `-xml` in the past and it worked but it doesn't anymore.

You can see all the options for CLI .NET Core 2.x [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore2x)

To publish the tests results into a specific folder, you should use the command below:

```
dotnet test --logger "trx;logfilename=mytests.trx" --results-directory ./somefolder/subfolder
```

Or

```
dotnet test --logger "trx;LogFileName=./somefolder/subfolder/mytests.trx"
```

The **trx** file is a XML file, so you could name it as *mytests.xml* instead of *mytests.trx*.

If you use VSTS, you can publish your tests to be shown in your build page using the command above in '.NET Core' task for test and the 'Publish Test Result' task.

The '.NET Core' task explains where it publishes the results as per screenshot below:

[image]

Once all done, your build page would look like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm using SonarQube, and by setting the logger (to nunit as I'm using NUnit3 for unit testing) the default file name TestResults.xml was correctly picked up and processed by SonarQube. NOTE: I needed to install the NuGet package NUnitXML.TestLogger in my Tests project to get this to activate.