# OpenCover throws missing assembly exception when running test with xunit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, asp.net-core-2.1, opencover

I am using the following bat file to generate code coverage report using OpenCover.

```
rmdir /s /q artifacts 
mkdir artifacts

set sharedProject[0]="src\BuildingBlocks\Shared\tests\Common.API.UnitTests"

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set sharedProject[') do (

cd %%s

"..\..\..\..\..\tools\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" ^
    -target:"c:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ^
    -targetargs:" xunit --fx-version 2.1.2 --no-build -xml ../../../../../artifacts/tests/%%s.xml" ^
    -mergeoutput ^
    -hideskipped:File ^
    -output:"..\..\..\..\..\artifacts\opencover.xml" ^
    -oldStyle ^
    -skipautoprops ^
    -filter:"+[companyName.*]*" ^
    -register:regsvr32 

cd ..\..\..\..\..

)
```

I run everything fine through visual studio, but when I try to run this script, some assemblies (Nuget package) cannot be found or loaded. So, some tests fail and others pass.

Before running the script I tried to delete the bin folders and execute:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

I've changed the above script to the follow one and everything worked fine:

```
rmdir /s /q artifacts 
mkdir artifacts

set sharedProject[0]="src\BuildingBlocks\Shared\tests\Common.API.UnitTests"

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set sharedProject[') do (

cd %%s

"..\..\..\..\..\tools\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" ^
    -target:"c:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ^
    -targetargs:"test --no-build" ^
    -mergeoutput ^
    -hideskipped:File ^
    -output:"..\..\..\..\..\artifacts\opencover.xml" ^
    -oldStyle ^
    -skipautoprops ^
    -filter:"+[companyName.*]*" ^
    -register:regsvr32 

cd ..\..\..\..\..

)
```

However I can't save the test results using "dotnet test". Any ideas why some Nuget packages fail to load when using dotnet xunit?

I am using .NET Core 2.1 and the two Nuget Packages which I am having problem are: Microsot.Extensions.Configuration.Abstraction and Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: I've just figured out that is possible to create test results in xml with dotnet test, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162247/3223737).